# JPA MySQL cant find created table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

I use JPA(Hibernate) with MySQL. I create table on application startup

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
```

insert testing data within my application:

```
public class ConfigurationService {

    @Inject
    private ConfigEntryDao configEntryDao;

    private List<ConfigEntry> configEntries;


    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        configEntryDao.insert(new ConfigEntry(ConfigNamespace.xchange_test, "Hello"));
        configEntryDao.insert(new ConfigEntry(ConfigNamespace.xchange_test_subtest, "World"));
        configEntries = configEntryDao.getAll();
    }

    public void tryTestValue() {
        System.out.println("Testing data from config db table Size: "+configEntries.size()+" Values:"+ configEntries.toString());
    }

}
```

I get correct data out, all good. Bud the problem is : **I cant find table that was supposed to be created where data is stored?!** Table is named ConfigEntry.

Server output(no errors, all expected output correct):

```
    Connected to server
[2018-01-21 02:25:21,226] Artifact xChange:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
14:25:21,323 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "xChange-1.0-SNAPSHOT" (runtime-name: "xChange-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
14:25:22,794 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for mysqldb
14:25:22,926 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'xChange-1.0-SNAPSHOT#mysqldb'
14:25:22,945 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: mysqldb
    ...]
14:25:22,966 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment xChange-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
14:25:23,009 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.10.Final}
14:25:23,011 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
14:25:23,013 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
14:25:23,016 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.5.Final
14:25:23,045 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
14:25:23,252 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-6) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.8.Final
14:25:23,395 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (version 6.0)
14:25:23,420 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) WELD-000900: 2.4.3 (Final)
14:25:23,465 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = xChange-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war_com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver_6_0
14:25:23,523 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
14:25:23,590 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'xChange-1.0-SNAPSHOT#mysqldb'
14:25:23,753 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
14:25:23,757 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work
14:25:23,799 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Envers integration enabled? : true
14:25:24,158 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Hibernate: 
14:25:24,158 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62)     
14:25:24,158 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62)     drop table ConfigEntry if exists
14:25:24,163 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Hibernate: 
14:25:24,163 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62)     
14:25:24,164 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62)     drop sequence if exists hibernate_sequence
14:25:24,166 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
14:25:24,169 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Hibernate: 
14:25:24,169 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62)     
14:25:24,169 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62)     create table ConfigEntry (
14:25:24,169 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62)         id bigint not null,
14:25:24,169 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62)         namespace varchar(255) not null,
14:25:24,169 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62)         value varchar(255) not null,
14:25:24,169 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62)         primary key (id)
14:25:24,169 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62)     )
14:25:24,175 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@63ca3829'
14:25:24,180 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
14:25:24,884 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.13.SP4  for context '/xChange'
14:25:26,131 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) Running on PrimeFaces 6.1
14:25:26,421 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class com.bisciak.xchange.rest.RestConfig$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
14:25:26,446 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/xChange' for server 'default-server'
14:25:26,475 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "xChange-1.0-SNAPSHOT" (runtime-name : "xChange-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
[2018-01-21 02:25:26,495] Artifact xChange:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2018-01-21 02:25:26,496] Artifact xChange:war exploded: Deploy took 5,269 milliseconds
14:25:41,458 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: 
14:25:41,458 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)     call next value for hibernate_sequence
14:25:41,510 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: 
14:25:41,510 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)     insert 
14:25:41,510 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)     into
14:25:41,510 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         ConfigEntry
14:25:41,510 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         (namespace, value, id) 
14:25:41,510 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)     values
14:25:41,510 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         (?, ?, ?)
14:25:41,521 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: 
14:25:41,521 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)     call next value for hibernate_sequence
14:25:41,522 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: 
14:25:41,522 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)     insert 
14:25:41,522 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)     into
14:25:41,522 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         ConfigEntry
14:25:41,522 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         (namespace, value, id) 
14:25:41,523 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)     values
14:25:41,523 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         (?, ?, ?)
14:25:41,534 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: 
14:25:41,534 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)     select
14:25:41,534 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         configentr0_.id as id1_0_,
14:25:41,534 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         configentr0_.namespace as namespac2_0_,
14:25:41,534 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         configentr0_.value as value3_0_ 
14:25:41,534 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)     from
14:25:41,534 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         ConfigEntry configentr0_
14:25:41,541 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Button Pressed
14:25:41,541 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Testing data from config db table Size: 2 Values:[ConfigEntry{id=1, namespace=xchange_test, value='Hello'}, ConfigEntry{id=2, namespace=xchange_test_subtest, value='World'}]
```

I try to check if table was created , bud cant see anything in IntelliJ or MySQL Workbench:
[image]
[image]

And here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<persistence-unit name="mysqldb">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xchange"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <!--Create tables automatically-->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
        <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>-->
        <!--<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>-->

        <!--Other sql shananigans-->
        <!--<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="script"/>-->
        <!--<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" value="META-INF/sql/create.sql"/>-->
        <!--<property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/sql/data.sql"/>-->
        <!--<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="script"/>-->
        <!--<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-script-source" value="META-INF/sql/drop.sql"/>-->

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Any ideas where to find created table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By valuing `"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"` with `create-drop`, the database schema will be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly.

`create-drop` makes sense as you want to have the exact schema (generally with the same data) at each start up.
It may be relevant in some types of application and it is always before running integration tests.

To create the database a single time use rather `create`.
Then if you want to keep the schema, for next starts of the application, change it to `validate` for example.

Comment: And could you please tell me where i can find tables created? I should be able to see them in workbench. Im running application in the background, and want to see table that was created, i changed property value to create, still cant see any table created, bud i can see it beign used properly in log, i have about 8 items in there, i can retrieve them all, bud cant see table.

Comment: I was just testing db, i didnt close application and expected DATA TO BE THERE still, i just want to  see data beign stored, while application is running in the background , open table that has been created in workbench

Comment: These are dropped, you will not see them after shutdown. Why not use "create" as value for `hbm2ddl.auto` ?`Besides, in your logs, h2 dialect is mixed with mysql driver and you have some warning about h2 dialect.

Comment: I know they will be dropped, even if i use create now , i still have same problem, i cant see table. Where is the table that was created?  I run application in the background(NOT CLOSED), i can see it beign used, bud cant find it, thats the whole problem i have. I want to be able to open this table in MySQL workbench or razorSQL or anywhere outside.

Comment: Enable logs to debug for `org.hibernate` package and restart. Try to identify the jdbc url used in logs.

Comment: Even if i use 'create' db is still dropped when i close application.Since i tried to change it to 'validate' later on, and table was not there.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl):

> create-drop
>
> Drop the schema and recreate it on SessionFactory startup. Additionally, **drop the schema on SessionFactory shutdown**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: I didnt close application, i want to just see data that was stored, while application in running in the background, i can see i stored 8 items into my table with 4 invocations of my method, now i want to see table in workbench, i refreshed all, and still cant see table thats beign used by my application anywhere.

Comment: Make sure you connect to the right database, on the right host. Try refreshing the list of tables or to disconnct/reconnect. Try another tool to inspect your database.